# Two child classes that only differ in a static const member

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a class `A` and two children `B` and `C` as follows:

```
class A {
   private:
     int x;
     template<class T>
     void setX(T &y);

   public:
     A();
};
class B : public A {
  private: 
    static const double y;

  public: 
      B();
};
class C : public A {
  private: 
    static const int y;

  public: 
      C();
 };
```

Both children only differ in the type of their static member `y`. The implementation of both C and B is the same except on the initialization of the static member:

```
B::B() : y (1.2) { setX(y) } 
C::C() : y (2) { setX(y) }
```

But the problem with this approach is that in the implementation file I have to write twice the same code for `B` and `C`. Is there a proper way to write this such that I do not need to write twice the call to `setX`?

In the real problem the classes are a little more complicated, but the situation at hand is the same. In particular, initialization of `y` requires non-trivial constructors and so it has to be in the implementation file.

Comment: You do realize that a static const is not a member variable?

Comment: It looks like what you want is crtp and enums instead of static consts

Comment: I do want static consts and perhaps the word "member" was unfortunate in my phrasing.

Comment: The example you gave is somewhat distorted. In real world this would be wrong or bad code. I guess your question is more of an academic nature, but then again, the concrete example is really not well chosen.

Comment: It seems that one solution could be to use c++14 variable template and move `y` to `A` as a static member template

Comment: @Elyasin I do not see anything wrong with the code in my example, if you point me to something concrete I'll edit to make the question clearer, but I think  this is a good abstraction of the problem I am currently facing.

Comment: I think having `int x` and `double y` is already not proper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a constructor for `A` as a function template.

```
class A {
    //....
public: 
    template<typename T>
    explicit A(T& y) {
        setX(y);
    }
};
```

And call that constructor from child classes:

```
class B : public A{
    //...
public:
    B() : A(1.2), y(1.2)
    {}
};
```

Only problem is that base class constructor gets called first, so you need to repeat constant data value twice. You can easily macro it though.